# str_split on strings with quotes and commas

Tags: r, string, stringr

I'm working with some messy categorical data which I'm trying to split out in separate cells. The data is split by commas, but in some outputs, there are commas within the categories themselves (such as categories 4 and 5 in the example below). In those instances the category is surrounded by quotes.

| category 1, category 2, category 3, "category, 4" |
| --- |
| category 1, category 2, "category, 4", "category, 5" |

The desired output would split the data into separate cells such as the table below

| category 1 | category 2 | category 3 | category, 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| category 1 | category 2 | category, 4 | category, 5 |

I've tried using str_split, but am unsure how to separate the categories without splitting the answers themselves.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table`'s `fread` does all this automatically for you:

```
dt <- data.table::fread(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simply reimporting this data using the `read.csv` tool.  The default quoting character is `"`, so it will automatically be able to ignore the commas inside doubly quoted terms.  Assuming you already have this data frame in R, you could try:

```r
write.csv(df, file="output.csv", col.names=FALSE)
df_new <- read.csv(file="output.csv", header=FALSE)
names(df_new) <- c("category 1", "category 2", "category 3", "category 4")
```

Answer (score 0):

We may also use `read.csv` with `textConnection`

```
df <- read.csv(textConnection('category 1, category 2, category 3, "category, 4"
          category 1, category 2, "category, 4", "category, 5"'), 
     check.names = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

-structure

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ category 1 : chr "category 1"
 $ category 2 : chr "category 2"
 $ category 3 : chr "category, 4"
 $ category, 4: chr "category, 5"
```